# Подключение библиотек к проекту C++

Tags: c++, include

Как можно подключить `#include`, но сразу ко всему проекту, а не прописывать много раз?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если разделять интерфейс класса то в заголовочном файле класса можно подключить библиотеку а когда будешь юзать класс подключится и библиотека